# Better approach than using append in div contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-plugins

I have a contenteditable div, in which if user presses enter after some content, two break tags gets created.

```
line 1
</br>
</br>
```

If user manually starts typing it becomes

```
line 1
</br>
line 2
</br>
```

But i am using jQuery append function to put some html content

```
jQuery('.editor').append(e.target.innerHTML);
```

But it becomes

```
line 1
</br>
</br>
html content
```

Is there any way to not have two line gap between the content?

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same kind of problem, And it also adds '&lt', '$gt', etc sometimes. I used the below regular expression to delete all the html tags. When you call the onblur event, inside the function use the below code to remove tags. It also works even if you copy and paste the content in the editable div.

```
x = x.replace(/(<[^\\>]*>|<br\/>|&amp;|amp;|&lt|&gt;)/g, '');
x = x.trim();
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.